# Add missing trailing commas in project

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, lint

Currently in the project I'm working on we have *3K+ Problems*, 577 of those are **Missing a required trailing comma.** It's very easy to fix, but at the same time it's very time consuming so...

**Question:**
Is there any way to set every missing trailing comma in project? Basically I want to reduce the overall time it may take me to make those monotonous changes.

Maybe it exists a dart package or VS Code extension that does that for me? Haven't found any.

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/flutter-fix.

Comment: Thanks very useful information @user18309290 but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 18):

Add [require_trailing_commas](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/require_trailing_commas.html) rule to `analysis_options.yaml`

```
  rules:
    require_trailing_commas: true
```

and run

```
dart fix --apply
```

See [dart fix](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-fix) for details.

Comment: Yes but this also tries to fix other issues in project that I don't want to have automatically fixed since it can break other stuff. I want to only add trailing commas in all project, nothing else.

Comment: So just add rules to false which you don't want to fix.

Comment: It's now possible to fix only specific issues, for example `dart fix --apply --code=require_trailing_commas`