# How can I adjust the formatting of Flutter code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, prettier

I would like this formatting to happen when I save the file

[image]

instead I get this upon save, even if I have manually formatted the code as I like.

[image]

my settings look like this

[image]

I have the flutter extension installed as well, as recommended by Flutter documentation.[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add missing trailing commas in project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651862/add-missing-trailing-commas-in-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a trailing comma.

```dart
Expense(
  {required this.title,
  required this.amount,
  required this.date,
  required this.category,})
```

When you run `dart format` (or use the equivalent integrated command on VSCode), the code will be formatted to:

```dart
Expense({
  required this.title,
  required this.amount,
  required this.date,
  required this.category,
})
```

The documentation has example of how trailing commas affect the formatting result: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/formatting#using-trailing-commas

You can also enable a lint that will tell you to always use trailing commas: https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/require_trailing_commas